# Ansible GCP dynamic inventory Failed to connect to the host via ssh Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, devops, ansible-inventory

**Configuration**

I followed the steps in the below links to set up my GCP dynamic inventory.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html
http://matthieure.me/2018/12/31/ansible_inventory_plugin.html

*In short, it was the below steps*

1. I installed the needed requisites.

`$ pip install requests google-auth1`

2. I created a service account with sufficient privileges. and set it's
   credentials.
3. I added the below to the /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg file

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = gcp_compute
```

4. I created a file called **hosts.gcp.yml** which holds the dynamic inventory setup (as shown below):

```
projects:
  - my-project-id
hostnames:                
  - name
filters: []
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: my/credentials_path.json
keyed_groups:
  - key: zone
```

and tried to run the below command which worked fine

```
macbook@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro Ansible % ansible-inventory --graph -i hosts.gcp.yml
@all:
  |--@_us_central1_a:
  |  |--test
  |--@ungrouped:
```

but when running the below command I got the following errors

```
macbook@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro Ansible % ansible -i hosts.gcp.yml all -m ping      
test | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname test: nodename nor servname provided, or not known",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

5. I then commented out the **- name** option from the **hosts.gcp.yml** file but got another error.

```
macbook@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro Ansible % ansible -i hosts.gcp.yml all -m ping
34.X.X.8 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: macbook@34.X.X.8: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

**This raises the following questions**

1- Is an SSH setup (creating users and copying ssh-keys) needed on the host machines when using dynamic Inventories (I don't think so)?

2- Why is ansible resorting to SSH though a dynamic Inventory is set? What if the host didn't expose SSH to the public or didn't have a public IP?

Your kind support is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

---

A more verbose output of the test

```
macbook@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro Ansible % ansible -i hosts.gcp.yml all -vvv -m ping
ansible [core 2.11.6] 
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/macbook/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/4.7.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/macbook/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.7 (default, Oct 13 2021, 06:45:31) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
redirecting (type: inventory) ansible.builtin.gcp_compute to google.cloud.gcp_compute
Parsed /Users/macbook/xxxx/Projects/xxxx/Ansible/hosts.gcp.yml inventory source with ansible_collections.google.cloud.plugins.inventory.gcp_compute plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
<34.132.201.8> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<34.132.201.8> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/macbook/.ansible/cp/026bb454d7 34.132.201.8 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<34.X.X.8> (255, b'', b'macbook@34.X.X.8: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
34.X.X.8 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: macbook@34.X.X.8: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
macbook@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro Ansible % ansible -i hosts.gcp.yml all -u ansible -vvv -m ping
ansible [core 2.11.6] 
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/macbook/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/4.7.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/macbook/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.7 (default, Oct 13 2021, 06:45:31) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
redirecting (type: inventory) ansible.builtin.gcp_compute to google.cloud.gcp_compute
Parsed /Users/macbook/xxxx/Projects/xxx/Ansible/hosts.gcp.yml inventory source with ansible_collections.google.cloud.plugins.inventory.gcp_compute plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
<34.132.201.8> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<34.132.201.8> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/macbook/.ansible/cp/46d2477dfb 34.132.201.8 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''
<34.X.X.8> (255, b'', b'ansible@34.X.X.8: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
34.X.X.8 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansible@34.X.X.8: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic inventory used only for collect data of your machines. If you want to get access into it, you should use SSH.

1. You must add your ssh-public key into VM's config and specify username
2. Add these lines in your `ansible.cfg` into the `[defaults]` section:

   ```
   host_key_checking = false
   remote_user = <username that you specify in VM's config>
   private_key_file = <path to private ssh-key>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

**Most probably Ansible can't establish ssh connection to the hosts (listed in `hosts.gcp.yml`) because they don't recognize ssh key of the machine that tries to ping them.**

Since you're using a macbook it's clear it's not a GCP VM. This means your GCP VM's don't have it's public ssh key by default.

You can [add your macboook's key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide) (found in `~ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the list of authorized keys that all GCP VM's will accept without any action on your side.

As for the first question - it's clearly DNS issue - however I'm not versed enough with this tool so You'd have tell if you can ping all the VM's using their DNS names directly from your mac's terminal. If so then the issue will be with Ansible configuration - otherwise it's DNS issue that prevent's your computer from using DNS names of your VM's.

**Additionally - `ansible-inventory --graph i /file/path` works "offline" and will only show the structure of your inventory regardles if it exists or works.**

Comment: thank you for your response, but I think there are some misconceptions in the above. As far as I understood the dynamic inventory uses the service user authentication file there for it shouldn't be using ssh in the first place. using the MacBook key/user will require me to add the key to the authorized_keys which is against the purpose of the dynamic inventory...
Last, the DNS recognition should be accomplished by the module which should do the mapping for the GCP components I assume.

Comment: Maybe just try from scratch; I've found [this tutorial](https://devopscube.com/ansible-dymanic-inventry-google-cloud/#Ansible_Dynamic_Inventory_Google_Cloud_Configuration) that explains the entire process of setting up an Dynamic Inventory for GCP.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of points in your question, one about inventory and one about connections.

**Inventory**

Your hosts.gcp.yml file is for a dynamic inventory plugin, as you said. What that means is that Ansible will run the GCP inventory plugin using the settings in that file, and the plugin will call GCP's API and generate a list of hosts to use as inventory. What the ansible-inventory command returns is what the ansible command will use also. In the example bit of output you pasted into your question, it looks like "test" is the only host it sees.

**Connections**

When you run the ansible command it will run the module against each host. It will first get the hostname returned by inventory, and then connect to that host using the transport type you specified. This is true even for the ping module. From the [ping module's doc page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html): "This is NOT ICMP ping, this is just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node." Meaning, it makes a connection.

**Potential Gotchas**

- Is inventory returning the correct hostname for your environment?
- What is the connection type you're using?

As for hostname, you set "hostnames" to "name" in your inventory file. Just be sure that's right. It might not be in your case.

As for connection type, if you haven't configured it, then by default it will be "smart", which uses SSH. You can find what you're using by doing this:

```
ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_TRANSPORT
```

You can change the connection type with the `--connection` option to the ansible command, or any of the other ways ansible lets you specify config options. Connection type is set independently from inventory type. They are two separate steps. The connection type is set via config or the command line option and is not based on what inventory plugin you're using.

**Your Problem**

To resolve your problem, figure out what hostnames ansible-inventory is actually returning, and what connection type you're using. Then see if you can connect to *that* hostname using *that* connection type. If the hostname being returned is "test" and your connection type is "smart" or "ssh", then try actually connecting with ssh to "test". From the command line, literally do `ssh test`. If that succeeds, then ansible should successfully connect to that host when it's run. If that doesn't succeed, then you have to do whatever you need to do to fix it in order for ansible to run successfully. Likewise, if you set a connection plugin different from SSH, then you should try to connect to your host using whatever that connection method uses in order to ensure that those types of connections are actually working.

More info about all this can be found in ansible's user guide. See, for example, "[Connecting to remote nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html#connecting-to-remote-nodes)".